# I am having trouble running this program and getting it to display my desired output

Tags: c#, output

I am getting this message when I try to run my code, I know it's incomplete.

> **Error 1 No overload for 'CalculateGrossPay_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' C:\Users\Jose A Soto\Desktop\Windows Forms Application\Windows Forms Application3\Form1.Designer.cs 169 WindowsFormsApplication3 46**

This is the line of code it displays when I double click the error:

> **this.CalculateGrossPay.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CalculateGrossPay_Click);**

I also can't get any thing to display.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string name;
    //private decimal;
    //private decimal;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private decimal CalculateGrossPay_Click(decimal hours, decimal rate)
    {
        decimal result=0.00m;
        decimal standardHours= 0.00m;
        decimal overtimeHours=0.00m;

        if (hours > 40)
        {               
            overtimeHours = (hours - 40) * ( (rate) * 1.5m);
            standardHours = 40 * rate;

            DisplayOutPut.Text = name+ NameTextBox.Text + ""; 

            DisplayOutPut.Text = "Gross Pay:" + result;
        }
        else
        {
            standardHours = hours * rate;
            DisplayOutPut.Text = "Hours:" + HoursTextBox.Text;
            DisplayOutPut.Text = "Rate:" + RateTextBox.Text;
        }

        result = standardHours + overtimeHours;
        return result;        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read the error message you have the solution: your event handler method doesn't match the event handler signature

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the delegate signature for Click Event. Here Click Event handler expects a method that matches the signature. `CalculateGrossPay_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

Do as follows,

```
private void CalculateGrossPay_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateGrossPay(decimal hrs, decimal rate)      ;
}

public void CalculateGrossPay(decimal hrs, decimal rate)
{
    //write your logic here, if you want to return some value, chnage return type
}
```

Comment: You can use backticks: ` so I can say `int x = 9;` and that will be in a preformatted code block. I'm not sure you get the syntax highlighting in that case though, just a fixed-width font.